# Question about robot jacobian

Tags: jacobian

I try to understand jacobian for robot control. I want to precisely understand how to build that matrix.
Can someone advice me course which explain how to create that matrix on a simple sample?

An other question about that matrix, I read that this matrix had to be process every step. Is it true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jacobian matrix is used to describe the relationship between the `configuration space` (space of joint angles) and the `task space` (space of end-effector pose)
as follows:

### $\textbf{$\dot{p}$} = \textbf{J(q)}\textbf{$\dot{q}$}$,

where $\textbf{J(q)}$ is the Jacobian matrix, $\textbf{p}$ and $\textbf{q}$ are vectors represented for the end-effector pose and joint angles, respectively.

Several tutorials:

https://realitybytes.blog/2017/06/20/forward-and-inverse-kinematics-jacobians-and-differential-motion/

https://automaticaddison.com/the-ultimate-guide-to-jacobian-matrices-for-robotics/

http://www8.tfe.umu.se/courses/elektro/RobotControl/Lecture07_5EL158.pdf

You can do further searching with keywords: Denavit–Hartenberg, kinematics modeling, etc.

Comment: "Jacobian matrix is used to describe the relationship between the configuration space (joint angles) and the task space (end-effector pose)": that's not correct as the relation needs to be intended in the differential manner, hence relating the joint velocities and the end-effector velocities. Please, amend your answer.

Comment: thanks, just added extra terms to make it clear.